# Error in VBA: Lost Connection to MySQL Server at 'reading authorization packet',system error 2

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

This is the error which I get after my macro executes for about 10 mins. The macro is basically performing the task to update the MySQL database every five seconds.

[image]

What could be wrong?

My macro is as below:

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 10 ' five seconds
Public Const cRunWhat = "UpdateMarketData"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub UpdateMarketData()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rad = 0



  TextStrang = TextStrang & "'"
  field2 = "cid"
  field1 = "bid"
  table1 = "MMbanner"

  For rowCursor = 3 To 4

    SQLStr = "UPDATE tbl_MarketData SET Mid = '" & Cells(rowCursor, 2) & "',Bid = '" & Cells(rowCursor, 5) & "',Offer = '" & Cells(rowCursor, 6) & "',DateEntered = '" & Format(DateTime.Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & "' WHERE IndexCode = '" & Cells(rowCursor, 1) & "'"
    Debug.Print SQLStr
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

    Cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=<Servername>; PORT=Portno; DATABASE=Databasename; USER=Username; PASSWORD=Password; OPTION=0;"

    Cn.Execute SQLStr
    rad = rad + 1
  Next
Set rs = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

Call StartTimer

End Sub


Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub


Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop creates two separate connections via `Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection` etc but `Cn.Close` is only called once after the `for` loop. Therefore, the first connection created isn't explicitly closed and **may** still be considered active by the server. Eventually you'll run out of available connections and things will grind to a halt.

Not sure if this is the cause of your problem but it's definitely worth fixing. I would create and open the connection prior to the `for` loop but keep the `Cn.Execute` part within the body of the loop

Comment: Thanks for the input. so what would be better option? Closing the connection inside the `for` loop? Or Opening the Connection before `for` loop and Closing the connection after `for` loop?

Comment: The second option: create and open the connection before the `for` loop and close the connection after the `for` loop

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try that out shortly and get back to you. Thanks for the help :) :)

Comment: Hey this still doesnot work out. Can you please suggest something else which may be causing this error? +1 for your help and your effort.

Comment: The MySQL manual suggests increasing the `connect_timeout` value on the MySQL server to resolve this - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html